# What is called '../' in a relative file/folder path?

Tags: path, naming

In a file path, the set of "words" or folder names required to specify a specific file in a hierarchy of directories is called the path to the file, which is called path name. Path name can be either absolute or relative. In relative form, a sort of patterns like `"./"`, `"../"`, `"../../"`, ... can be used to show the file/folder depth corresponding to the project base folder.
I know what they do or implying by behavior, but what are they called? Do they have a specific name? For example, what is called `"../"` or `"..\"` in a file system?

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, it is called levelup notion.

Let's start with defining path:

> A path is a slash-separated list of directory names followed by either
> a directory name or a file name. A directory is the same as a folder.

Then, we look at types of paths: Absolute and relative paths!

An absolute, or full, path begins with a drive letter, whereas a relative path refers to a location that is relative to a current directory.

In relative paths we may use dot and double-dot symbols. A dot here means the current directory itself. And the double-dot notation, which is called level-up, is used for moving up in the hierarchy.

[image]

- Now to change the directory using the dot notion we do as follows:
  A single dot represents the current directory itself. for example:
  in a command line interface (e.g. PowerShell):

`cd .` will not change the directory as itself point to the current directory.
[image]

- To change the directory using the level-up notion we do as follows:
  each double-dot notions takes you one level up, meaning one folder closer to the base drive or root folder in the hierarchy.
  Look at the example below for different cases of using levelup notions:
  [image]